# How to call callback function or handle

Tags: c#, function, callback, overriding, naudio

I have this functions:

```
 public WaveIn(WaveCallbackInfo callbackInfo)
        {
            this.DeviceNumber = 0;
            this.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1);
            this.BufferMilliseconds = 100;
            this.NumberOfBuffers = 3;
            this.callback = new WaveInterop.WaveCallback(Callback);
            this.callbackInfo = callbackInfo;
            callbackInfo.Connect(this.callback);
        }
```

How do I call it?

```
WaveIn(callbackInfo: ????);
```

And I whant to change for example this parameters in here:

```
this.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1);
```

If I can't change those parameters in callback can I override it?

Thank you

Comment: Ok, it looks like `WaveCallbackInfo` is a class that is part of NAudio. So your question is basically how to use this part of NAudio, right? That wasn't obvious to me at first glance.

Comment: Yes you are correct about Naudio, I want to be able to change these parameters from user input, first is frequency, second bits, and third is number of channels.

Comment: And I don't know how to do it. I have tried to override it but I haven't done it correctly.

Comment: Can you change the parameters and code of the `WaveIn` method?

Comment: Anyone? I didn't think that this would be such a hard question :)

Comment: Could you be more specific? Is that code from the implementation of NAudio? In that case, if you wanted to change it, just download the source and compile it with your changes (though questionable if that's what you should do). If not - well what is it? Your implementation of that interface you got? Sorry, but I guess the reason why nobody answered yet is because your question isn't very clear.

Comment: I am really sorry if I didn't be more specific. So I am using NAudio library. This method is in dll file. I can't change it and I can't override it. I mean probbably I don't know. I would like to pass data to that function so I can change some arguments inside such as `this.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1);` I hope I have been more clear now.

Comment: nobody knows how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you ignore that constructor and call the default one

```
var waveIn = new WaveIn();
```

if you want to specify a different recording WaveFormat, just set the WaveFormat property (before you start recording)

```
waveIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 16, 2);
```